# Android bootstrap

Tags: android, menu, sequence, boot, launcher

Considering an ICS device's boot sequence,
what is the android side (java, not talking about the underlying linux system) bootstrap application stack?
I know that the application that realizes the bottom ICS menu bar is SystemUI.apk, but what has been loaded before?
Who (if any) starts up without receiving any broadcast intent?
May be it is the ActivityManager that after loaded starts Launcher and SystemUI?

Thanks in advance
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'application stack' and what are you trying to do? Generally, the system server starts all services and the activity manager. Then the activity managers sends and `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME` which results in the launcher starting. When you press an icon on the launcher, it calls the activity manager, which in turns talks to zygote, which forks itself to create a process for the new app.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I think you have already find me a response but let's try to dig it more. I need to verify the user credential (industrial device, not commercial) against an LDAP directory to gain the access to a tablet. I'd like to verify it BEFORE loading the launcher and the status bar. I'd like a completely useless device if the credentials are not valid. Starting from your answer, i've to work at system server or activity manager level. Ok for you?